# Keep only specific nodes from xml with php and save it in another xml file

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml feed (feed.xml) as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
 <item>
  <itemcode>432432</itemcode>
  <title>test</title>
  <platform>test</platform>
  <genre>test</genre>
  <pegi>test</pegi>
  <price_eur>16</price_eur>
  <ean>436436436436</ean>
  <release_date>2019-09-06</release_date>
  <image_url>testtest</image_url>
  <stock>41</stock>
  <manufacturer>test</manufacturer>
  <oem/>
  <weight_g>100.0</weight_g>
  <length_mm>170.0</length_mm>
  <width_mm>135.0</width_mm>
  <height_mm>15.0</height_mm>
</item>
 .....
</items>
```

And I need only 3 of those nodes (itemcode, stock, price_eur) that I insert them into a mysql database as:

```
  mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->load('feed.xml');
 $arrFeeds = array();
 foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
 $itemRSS = array ( 
   'sku' => $node->getElementsByTagName('itemcode')->item(0)->nodeValue,
   'stock' => $node->getElementsByTagName('stock')->item(0)->nodeValue,
  'price' => $node->getElementsByTagName('price_eur')->item(0)->nodeValue
  );
  array_push($arrFeeds, $itemRSS);
  //print_r($arrFeeds);
   }


  $counter = 0;
  foreach( $arrFeeds as $RssItem){
   $sku = $RssItem["sku"];
      $stock = $RssItem["stock"];
$price = $RssItem["price"];
   $sql = "INSERT INTO table(sku,stock,price) VALUES ('" . $sku . "','" . $stock . "','" . $price . "')";
$counter++;
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  }

    echo $counter;

    mysqli_close($conn);
```

How can i load the initial feed.xml and save it with another name only keeping those 3 nodes itemcode, stock, price_eur before importing them into the database so the xml file is smaller and the whole process faster?

Comment: Can you apply a transform (xslt) to the xml?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the XML will only speed up the XML parsing (`DOMDocument::load()`) slightly. You still need to spend the additional time for the transformation if separately.

I suggesting checking the syntax for mass inserts to reducing the amount of insert queries.

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name
  VALUES 
    (...), 
    (...), 
    (...)
```

Or use MySQL [LOAD XML](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-xml.html)

```sql
LOAD XML
  INFILE 'file_name'
  INTO TABLE table_name
  ...
```

However building a new XML file can be done by copying the nodes.

```php
$source = new DOMDocument();
$source->load('feed.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($source);

$target = new DOMDocument();
// copy items element without descendants
$target->appendChild(
    $targetItems = $target->importNode($source->documentElement, FALSE)
);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/items/item') as $sourceItem) {
    // copy item element without descendants
    $targetItems->appendChild(
        $targetItem = $target->importNode($sourceItem, FALSE)
    ); 
    // fetch nodes filtered by name
    foreach($xpath->evaluate('*[self::itemcode or self::stock or self::price_eur]') as $sourceChild) {
        // copy item element with descendants
        $targetItem->appendChild(
          $target->importNode($sourceChild, TRUE)
        );
    } 
}

$target->save('feed_reduced.xml');
```

Comment: thnx for your answer. As i see in the LOAD XML scenario all nodes--> columns will (must) be imported, something I don't need. As for your new xml building code it results to the same resource and time consumption as when I parse the whole xml file and insert the 3 nodes i need, so I think there is no point in doing it. I wonder if anyone with a 16mb xml feed (20000 items) have so much trouble parsing it in a mysql database.

Comment: LOAD XML allows to specify the fields, scroll down to the more complex examples. The problem of a large XML files is usually not CPU but memory. The standard approach in PHP  for this is to combine XMLReader with DOM. Still, if you use PHP the most efficient thing is to reduce the database queries by using mass inserts. You parse the XML and collect the data for n records, then insert them with a single query.